# How to tell whether a particular font includes a particular character in PDF::API2

Tags: perl, pdf, unicode, fonts, truetype

I use `PDF::API2` in my Perl application to embed OCR 
output behind the corresponding image, allowing the resulting PDF to be searched, as the OCR 
output can be extracted with `pdftotext`.

At the moment, as soon as the application sees a non-ASCII character in 
the OCR output, it switches from PDF core fonts to TTF. However, this 
is really hacky, as the core fonts include most Western European 
characters. TTF is only necessary for Greek, Russian, Japanese, 
etc.

How can I tell whether a particular font includes a particular 
character (including the CMAP table so that extraction with 
`pdftotext` works)?

Comment: Have you looked into [Font::TTF::Font](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Font::TTF::Font)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the glyph-specific methods?

http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDF-API2/lib/PDF/API2/Resource/BaseFont.pm#GLYPH_RELATED_METHODS

Failing that, perhaps rendering the glyph (to a separate document) and measuring it?